# How to write a s3object downloaded from s3 to a file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-s3, modelandview

I am trying to download s3object from s3 bucket then write that object to a html file. S3 object is downloading but when I try to create a file and try to write to that file I am facing NullPointerException, I am not sure what's wrong with my code. Please check my code below and any help or guidance in this regard is much helpful.

```
 S3Object s3Object = s3Services.downloadFile("filename", "bucketName");
        if (s3Object == null) {
                throw new Exception("Object not found");
            }   
            File file = new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"+randomfilename+"."+"html")); // NullPointerException here
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write(s3Object.getObjectContent().toString());
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
            Files.copy(s3Object.getObjectContent(), file.toPath());
            input.close();
            ModelAndView v= new  ModelAndView(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"+randomfilename+"."+"html"));
            return v;
```

My use case is I'm trying to let user customize his text and store that customized file to s3 which I am doing successfully now when user logs in next time if he has generated his customized document I am suppose to populate him that page so to achieve to this I have to download user specific file from s3 and write it to some html file and display him that page.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the Null Pointer exception?

Answer (score 0):

seems like request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"+randomfilename+"."+"html") return null - you can check it by breaking the line:

`File file = new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"+randomfilename+"."+"html")); // NullPointerException here`

into

`String fileName = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"+randomfilename+"."+"html");
System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);
File file = new File(fileName);`

other than that you don't need to use FileWriter if you use Files.copy into a path so you can remove those lines:

`FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
writer.write(s3Object.getObjectContent().toString());
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
input.close();`

Comment: Hi, no it didn't work. still the same NullPointerException.